# Do users prefer polls that come up with the option to answer straight away? or a notification that a new poll exists with a link to go vote?

Tags: poll

When checking a live sports match online, e.g. in match centres; are there any UX insights on whether users prefer polls that come up with the option to answer straight away? or a notification that a new poll exists with a link to go vote? 
What would be that variables that affect that decision?

Comment: Related: [Should current poll progression be shown before or after casting a vote](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30504/show-the-current-votes-before-or-after-voting)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience(on a news related website), the user will prefer a link rather than be presented with a poll which they may not want to take part in.

Using a link could result in a lower conversion rate, however I would surmise that the quality of data may be higher as the users have consciously decided to take part in the poll.

Answer (score 0):

I think people want to take action as soon as possible. In the same time the user probably does not want to lose its focus just for your poll, or does not want his whole screen used by a poll they don't intend on filling anyway. An alternative could be to use a progressive disclosure where you offer people to answer a question, and if they accept, you keep them where they are and expand the prompt to show the question, then close it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web site I use regularly I don't usually mind filling in a poll (single question) or survey (many questions).

What does annoy me is that the popup "Would you like to take a poll/survey?" gives me only 2 options:

1. Take it right away, now.
2. Don't take it.

What I'd like is a 3rd option, "I'll take it, but later" as the poll/survey wasn't the reason I came to the site. I've yet to see suh a poll/survey that allows me to easily pick it up later, I click "No" and then there's no way to get to it, if I really want to take it, I usually revisit the site in a different browser to trigger the popp again.

If it's a single-question poll, I've seen them done in-line without any popup, kinda like an ad on the right-hand-side of any stackexchange site.
It's always there, easily accessible and always available with no popup.